# How to get CKEditor 4.x "Spell Check as You Type" feature to work inside a Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, richtextarea

[CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) allows a sophisticated JavaScript-based rich text editor to be "made to order" via it's [builder page](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) where you can choose to include hundreds of plugins. This editor can then be used in a Visualforce page.

One of the options is [SCAYT](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/scayt) or "Spell Check as You Type". The spelling dialog part of this works for me so it is *not a basic configuration problem*. But the "as you type" part *doesn't*. I've spent some time in the debugger trying to make sense of where the problem might be but have not been successful.

(The request to https://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/script/ssrv.cgi fires from the dialog but not as text is entered as it does in the [demo page](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/spellchecker.html).)

**Has anyone got the CKEditor 4.x SCAYT feature to work inside a Visualforce page, and if so how?**

I'm prepared to debug further to resolve the problem if it is in my code but would like some confidence that there isn't a fundamental problem...

**PS** Looks like the problem is being caused by other logic in my page. See my own answer.

Comment: Just tweaked the title to be a little more concise, since the body of your question contains the more verbose version of the same question. Obviously feel free to roll back if you disagree. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Happy with the improvement - thanks. I know this is quite a niche question: just hoping to get lucky.

Comment: That's where SFSE really shines. You running into this issue could easily help someone five years down the road who feels like surely no one else have ever run into it before.

Comment: I'd [run into something similar with the CKEditor in the developer forums](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/11/rejecting-salesforce-ckeditor-and.html). In that case I opted to just add the Source button and use the browsers built in spell checker.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks; I did look at your post but just saw that scayt was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will probably leave this turned off and recommend customers use https://www.grammarly.com/ instead.

But for completeness, with no definitive answer here, I did what I should have done to start with and created the simplest possible test case page listed below. In this the "Spelling Check as You Type" *does work*.

So my problem is self-inflicted somewhere in the more complex page I was initially adding CKEditor to.

```
<apex:page>

<apex:form>
    <apex:inputTextarea styleClass="xyz-ckeditor"/>
    <apex:inputTextarea styleClass ="xyz-ckeditor"/>
</apex:form>

<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQuery, 'js/jquery.js')}" />
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditor, 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}" />
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditor, 'ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')}" />
<script>
(function($) {
    function applyEditors() {
        var config = {
            toolbar: [
                {name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
                {name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent']},
                {name: 'insert', items: ['Table' ]},
                {name: 'clipboard', items: ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SelectAll']},
                {name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', 'Scayt']},
                {name: 'source', items: ['Source']},
                {name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize']},
            ],
            scayt_autoStartup: true,
            disableNativeSpellChecker: true,
        };
        $('.xyz-ckeditor').ckeditor(config);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        applyEditors();
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>

</apex:page>
```